# SWIFT: showing the second cell instead of first cell when present a ViewController

Tags: swift, tableview

Say I have a UIViewController with three tableViewCells: A, B, C (list view, not full screen).
Cell A B and C contains data Biz from an Array [Biz]
When I tap cell B to present to a new controller, I want the new controller to show B (full screen now) on the screen instead of A, and if I scroll down or up, I could see cell A and Cell C.

How do I achieve that?

My code:

Old VC:

```
var post: Biz?
var posts: [Biz]()

...

func didTapCell(post: Biz, posts: [Biz]) {
  //should I pass any other things to the new VC?
    let vc = SearchHomeVC()
    vc.bizs = posts
    vc.biz = post
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

New VC:
Need help here

Comment: So you want to push a new vc that shows an expanded cell and still allow the user to scroll up and down?  How will the user know they can scroll?

Comment: first time user will see a hand swipe animation